# Should "The" be used before each element in a list

Tags: grammar, lists

Which is correct -

"The cheese, the milk and the potatoes"

or

"The cheese, milk and potatoes"

Comment: Depends on context.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you provide the context?

Comment: The specific sentence is "The limit of detection, lower limit of quantification and upper limit of quantification should be tested regarding..."

However I'm also curious about the rules regarding this, and would appreciate any resources!

Comment: Do you want them tested individually or as a group?

Comment: They are each tested individually.

Comment: Are you talking about cheese, milk and potatoes as types of food, or about particular samples of them?

Comment: Kate - Types of food